# CSS centering objects inside a box with display:grid?

Tags: css

I have a box with text and a few buttons. I spent hours trying to figure out how to center it. Finally, I just decided to do a display:grid and align and justify center. In terms of best practices, would this be acceptable to do repeatedly? Is there a better way to go about centering it? I have tried implementing setting the cta-box to text-align center and the container to display:inline-block but that did not work either. I am certain I am making a simple mistake but cannot figure it out. Below it is working perfectly with grid; I just want to know if there is a better way. Thanks!

```css
.cta-box {
    display:grid;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 11% 0 0 5%;
    width: 671px;
    height: 285px;
    border-bottom: 7px solid green;
    background-color: rgba(29, 60, 89, .70);

}

.cta-box-container{
    padding:0px 19px 2px 19px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    
}
```

```html
  
    <div class="cta-box">
            <div class="cta-box-container">
                <h1> We can facilitate your transportation needs.</h1>
                <p class="white_text">sfgsd sdgsdf sdfsd fsdf insert more text here about what it should say </p>
                
                   <div class="buttons_cta">
                    <a class="cta_contact" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    <a href="#" class="cta_rates">See our Rates</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  

[enter image description here][1]
```

this is what it looks like when I do display flex on the cta-box.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSU5E.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `flex` layout.

```css
.cta-box {
  margin: 11% 0 0 5%;
  width: 671px;
  height: 1140px;
  border-bottom: 7px solid green;
  background-color: rgba(29, 60, 89, .70);
}

.cta-box-container{
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cta-box">
  <div class="cta-box-container">
    <h1> We can facilitate your transportation needs.</h1>
    <p class="white_text">sfgsd sdgsdf sdfsd fsdf insert more text here about what it should say </p>

    <div class="buttons_cta">
      <a class="cta_contact" href="#">Contact Us</a>
      <a href="#" class="cta_rates">See our Rates</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That was one of the first things I did but it made them all go side by side and it was not actually centered. I am still having that issue. if you set the box height to 1400px you will also see that it does not center vertically and stays on the top (centered horizontally) with display flex.

Comment: you have to add `flex` property to the **parent** element. Here I centered elements **inside the box** by adding `flex` property to the **box**. If you want to center the box then try adding **flex property and height** to the `parent` element.

Comment: The parent is cta-box but it is also in the body section. Would I have to add flex to the body as well? thanks (I attached an image of the issue)

Comment: I edited the answer, check if it solves the problem.